# nodejs + grpc-node server much slower than REST

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-go, grpc-node

I have implemented 2 services A and B, where A can talk to B via both gRPC (using grpc-node with Mali) and pure HTTP REST calls.

The request size is negligible.

The response size is 1000 items that look like this:

```
{
   "productId": "product-0",
   "description": "some-text",
   "price": {
      "currency": "GBP",
      "value": "12.99"
   },
   "createdAt": "2020-07-12T18:03:46.443Z"
}
```

Both A and B are deployed in GKE as services, and they communicate over the internal network using kube-proxy.

What I discovered is that the REST version is a lot faster than gRPC.  The REST call's p99 sits at < 1s, and the gRPC's p99 can go over 30s.

**Details**

Node version and OS: `node:14.7.0-alpine3.12`

Dependencies:

```
    "google-protobuf": "^3.12.4",
    "grpc": "^1.24.3",
    "mali": "^0.21.0",
```

I have even created client-side-TCP-pooling by setting the gRPC option `grpc.use_local_subchannel_pool=1`, but this did not seem to help.

The problem seems to be the server side, as I can see that from the log that the grpc lib's `call.startBatch` call took many seconds to send data of size ~51kb.  This is way slower than the REST version.

I also checked the CPU and network of the services are healthy.  The REST version could send > 2mbps, whereas the gRPC version only manages ~150kbps.

Running `netstat` on service B (in gRPC) shows a number of ESTABLISHED TCP connections (as expected because of TCP pooling).

My suspicion is that the grpc-core C++ code is somehow less optimal than REST, but I have no proof.

Any ideas where I should look at next?  Thanks for any helps

## Update 1

Here're some benchmarks:

### Setup

`Blazemeter --REST--> services A --gRPC/REST--> service B`

- request body (both lags) is negligible
- `service A` is a node service + Koa
- `service B` has 3 options:

  - `grpc-node`: node with grpc-node
  - `gRPC + Go`: Go implementation of the same gRPC service
  - `REST + Koa`: node with Koa
- `Blazemeter --> service A`: response payload is negligible, and the same for all tests
- `serivce A --> service B`: the gRPC/REST response payload is 1000 of `ProductPrice`:

```
message ProductPrice {
  string product_id = 1; // Hard coded to "product-x", x in [0 ... 999]
  string description = 2; // Hard coded to random string, length = 10
  Money price = 3;
  google.protobuf.Timestamp created_at = 4; // Hard coded
}

message Money {
  Currency currency = 1; // Hard coded to GBP
  string value = 2;  // Hard coded to "12.99"
}

enum Currency {
  CURRENCY_UNKNOWN = 0;
  GBP = 1;
}
```

The services are deployed to Kubernetes in GCP,

- instance type: `n1-highcpu-4`
- 5 pods each service
- 2 CPU, 1 GB memory each pod
- kube-proxy using cluster IP (not going via internet) (I've also test headless with `clusterIP: None`, which gave similar results)

### Load

50rps

### Results

#### service B using grpc-node

[image]

#### service B using Go gRPC

[image]

#### service B using REST with Koa

[image]

#### Network IO

[image]

### Observations

- `gRPC + Go` is roughly on par with `REST` (I thought gRPC would be faster)
- `grpc-node` is 4x slower than `REST`
- Network isn't the bottleneck

Comment: It's hard to address the results of a benchmark like this without knowing the details of the methodology. The mention of TCP connection pooling in particular is concerning: a single gRPC client talking to a single server should generally have a single TCP connection. If you are establishing multiple connections, the connection startup time may have a disproportionate impact on your results.